# When a cyclic R-module is unitary

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

First I'd like to say that the Wiki-page for [cyclic module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_module) (specificaly, the **Definition** part) is somewhat thoughtlessly written because the ring $R$ may be an arbitrary ring hence $(x)=Rx$ is not true in general.

Well, let's go down to business.

We know that if $R$ is a ring with identity and $A$ is a cyclic (left)$R$-module and is unitary, then $A$ can be written as $A = Ra$ where $a$ is the generator of $A$.

**Question**:
I wonder whether  the converse holds, that is:
if $R$ is a ring with identity and $A$ is  a cyclic $R$-module,
is $A$ necessarily unitary, i.e. is $1_R a = a$ true (here $a$ is the 
generator of $A$)?

**My attempt**:
$\forall r\in R, r (1_Ra-a) = ra-ra=0,\text{hence } Ann_R(1_Ra-a)=R.$
Note that this does not imply  $1_ra-a=0$ in general, but can we go a step further to show $1_Ra-a=0$ based on our assumptions above ?

added: **Definition.** $R$ is a ring with identity $1_R$ and $A$ is a (left)$R$-module.
We say $A$ is  **unitary** if $1_Ra=a$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: What do you mean by a unitary module? $1_Ra = a$ for any element $a$, in any $R$-module, by definition

Comment: Yes. If $R$ is a ring with identity $1_R$, $A$ is a (left)$R$-module s.t. $1_Ra=a$ for all $a\in A$, then $A$ is unitary. In my question, since $A$ is cyclic, it suffices for $A$ to be unitary if $1_Ra=a$ where $a$ is the generator.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. Part of the definition of a module is that $1_R$ acts as the identity. I have not heard of this notion of unitary module before, but if by unitary you mean $1_R$ acts as the identity, then every module is unitary

Comment: Well, I have only read Hungerford's $Algebra$(GTM73), where the definition of a module is perhaps slightly different from what you said~

Comment: It seems that I should add the definition of unitary to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $A$ must be unitary.

Let $u = 1_R a - a$.  As you have shown, $u$ is annihilated by $1_R$.  But we assumed that $A$ was generated by $a$, so there must exist some $r\in R$ with $u=ra$.

Then, we have: $0 = 1_R u = 1_R (r a) = (1_R r) a = ra = u$.  And so $u=0$, therefore $1_R a = a$.  It follows readily that $1_R$ fixes every element of $A$.